# -ness suffix etymology

Tags: etymology, suffixes

What is the etymology of the suffix '-ness'? I have come across it in OE texts but always  assumed it was a later borrowing.

Comment: Hi Rita Barker, welcome to the site. One of our go to resources is [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com) and they have [the etymology of -ness](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-ness&searchmode=none). Is there more than this that you're interested in?

Comment: I think you are referring to the (obs) noun 'ness' as Loch Ness, not the suffix as in 'happiness'.There is no equivalent in German (cf -'heit/keit) which puzzles me.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the second link, which talks about "suffix of action, quality or state".

Comment: @Rita - follow Matt's link. It has the etymology of -ness and its germanic roots. Not Loch Ness.

Comment: Oops! There is a German equivalent (-nis). Thanks for info Matt. Rita

Answer (score 11):

This suffix is widespread among the Germanic languages, though it is no longer productive in all:

- English *-ness* (Old English *-nes(s), -nis(s), -nys(s)*)
- Dutch *-nis* (Old Dutch *-nussi, -nisse, -nesse*)
- German *-nis* (Old High German *-nissi, -nessi, -nassi, -nussi*)
- Gothic *-nassus*

There is no consensus yet about why the first vowel varies so widely among the Germanic languages.

The *-n-* was originally not part of the suffix, but of the stem of many root words that `*`*-assus* was often attached to; it was later stolen by the suffix and became part of it, which already happened in Proto-Germanic.

The *-s* is probably the nominative ending (my own, reasonable interpretation of the *Woordenboek der Nederlandsche Taal*).

That leaves `*`-*assu*- as the basic suffix (the *WNT* confirms this). It in turn came from `*`*-ad-tu-*: ***-ad-*** is a Germanix suffix forming verbs out of adjectives (Gothic *-at(j?)-*), and ***-tu-*** is a suffix forming abstract nominal stems from verbal stems.

---

The suffix *-esse* in French (*fin-esse* etc.) is not directly related: it comes from Latin *-itia* (*fin-itia*). The *-ia* part is probably the common Proto-Indo-European suffix **-ia/ya* indicating mass nouns; it is possible that the *-(i)t-* part is related to Germanic *-tu-* in `*`*-ad-tu-*, but that seems doubtful.

Comment: Is there a common ancestor for the Germanic 'ness' eg.

Comment: @RitaBarker: I'm still trying to find out whether there is a Proto-Indo-European origin of the Proto-Germanic suffix; I don't have my etymological dictionaries on hand.

Comment: Is there a common ancestor for the Germanic 'ness' and the Old French<Latin 'esse' (cf finesse). They seem to perform the same function.-Rita

Comment: @RitaBarker: See my edit above: probably not, but we can't be sure. It is alas very hard to find etymological information on suffixes earlier than Proto-Germanic and Latin/Greek.

Answer (score 2):

Oxford Dictionary Online states that it is of Germanic origin:

http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-ness?q=-ness

Comment: I am surprised there appears to be no near equivalent in German where '-heit/keit'are the norm, which survive in English as '-hood'.

Comment: @RitaBarker: Although they have common origins, the two languages (i.e. English and German) can't evolve and change in the same way. The people and the cultures that have shaped them are, after all, different.

Comment: Which of course I realise.

Comment: @RitaBarker: It survives in German in words such as 'Geheimnis' - secret.

Comment: @BarrieEngland and Finsternis - darkness (for an example where the English translation also has "-ness")

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a much simpler explanation for "ness". It might simply mean "to carry/contain". In Russian language for example, the word "нести" (nesti) means to carry and a lot of the Slavic words contain this ending (in the form of "nost' since nosit' means to carry as well).

Vernost' (Faithfullness) - to carry 'vera' (faith)
Drevnost' - ancient times - to carry antiquity
Vechnost (eternity) - to carry a vek/veche (decade)
Blagodarnost' (gratitude/kindness) - to carry blagodarstvo (gratitude)
Mrachnost' (darkness) - to carry mrak (dark)
Duhovnost' (spirituality) - to carry a spirit

Now some English words; goodness, sickness, willingness, business, nest, honest (one who carries honor)
I am sure you can come up with many other examples.

On the other hand "less" would mean the exact opposite of "ness"
Ex: faithless, godless, fearless, speechless

There might also be a relation to "is-ist-es-est"

I am not a serious etymologist, just wanted to share my observations since I speak both languages.

Comment: You're right that _-nost'_ is a common suffix for abstract nouns in Slavonic languages, and I too have wondered whether it might share an origin with _-ness_. But I don't think your _nesti_ theory works semantically; and creating a suffix out of an independent root is exceedingly rare (though it has happened in the Romance languages, which use suffixes derived from Latin _mente_ (originally "with [an XXX] mind") for adverbs).

Answer (score -4):

I think that is coming from the greek *estia* which means fireplace and home.
Through latin/old french *-esse* and old germanic *-ness* you have a great number of nouns nowadays. It is so obvious to me.

Comment: It may be obvious to you, but it is in no way true. The Germanic suffix is attested in Gothic (from the 4th and 5th centuries), long before Old French. At that time, the Latin suffix was still _-itia_, which can in no way yield Gothic _-nassus_. The Greek word—which, incidentally, is not ‘estia’, but _ἑστίᾱ/ἱστίη_ ‘hestiā/histiē’—is also entirely unrelated.